# Is it safe to store small images in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase database and now I'm moving to Firestore. Are there any problems if I store small images in Firestore that are encoded to Base64? I have a collection `sport_products` where I have documents with all details and I also have an icon with the corresponding brand and I want to store all data + icon in a single place. Is it safe?

Comment: Yes it is safe. You just have to set read write rules for FireStore.

Comment: When you upload any image to your FireStore. it will return you Download Url of that image. You can then store that url + data in your Firebase Database.

Comment: @AliAhmed Thanks but don't want to store the image in Firebase Storage but in Firestore. That's the ideea, to have all data and image in one place. Is it ok?

Comment: you want to store image as Base 64 in Firestore ?

Comment: @AliAhmed Yes, this what I was asking, if it is safe to do this.

Comment: I never tried to store long strings like Base 64 in Fireabse. it is safe but i'm not sure Firebase accepts that long data or not.

Comment: @AliAhmed I'll wait for other answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to base64 encode anything in Firestore.  It has a native binary field type called "[bytes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)".  base64 will just make the data larger for no reason (unless you really only intend to consume that data in base64 format).

You have a [maximum document size of 1MB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields), so as long as you never go over that limit for all the data in that document combined, you won't have a problem.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks a ton.

Comment: How do you store data as "bytes" instead of a string/base64? I couldn't find any documentation on it. An array with numbers that are 0-255, perhaps? (in which case it would detect it matches, and use "bytes" as the internal storage instead of "array")

Comment: @Venryx The Firestore SDK infers the type of the field based on the type of the object you pass to it.  I don't know how it works for each platform, but you're likely going to pass in some language-native byte array or buffer.

Comment: I looked into the source code, and the JS/web type that gets stored as the "bytes" type in Firestore appears to be `Blob`. Code in question: `else if (value instanceof Blob) return new BlobValue(value);`

Comment: For others reading, apparently a firebase-specific version of Blob is needed. An example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53672081/2441655

Comment: I don't see "bytes" as an available field in the dropdown.

Comment: @pyetti I'm sure that's just because you can't use the console to enter raw bytes.

Comment: Yeesh. That makes total sense. I need to get some sleep. Thanks Doug.